# A Phone/Tablet with WiFi

Tags: wifi, smartphones, tablet

I want a phone, and I don't need 3G/4G/5G/Whatever other Gs there are, just WiFi. I have been considering the [LG Optimus Exceed 2](http://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-VS450PP-optimus-exceed-2).

### Max Price: $40 including shipping
Location: USA

### Requirements

- Screen size must be in between **4"** and **5.5"**
- Resolution must be **higher or equal** to **800 x 400**
- Must be touchscreen
- Must have **802.11g WiFi** or **better**.
- Must have at least **4GB** of **internal storage** and have at least **1.25GB** available
- Must have either **Android** or **Windows**
- MicroSD slot **must support up to 32GB!**
- Must support **class 10** SD cards
- Must have a **speaker and microphone**
- Chassis should be less than **0.5"** thick

### I don't care if...

- it's prepaid
- it doesn't have 2G/3G/4G
- it doesn't have a rear camera

### Strong Preferences

- being able to install apps on the MicroSD card
- screen size greater than **4.4"**
- front camera resolution greater than **1920 x 1080**
- **12 hours** of endurance with the battery **(standby)** and at least **3 hours** when **being used**
- I would like it to boot up before **the next ice age comes and goes!!!**

Comment: Most android phones (if not all) are 3g capable at the least and have rear cameras. I'd recommend looking into Chinese markets or Indian markets. They both have pretty cheap phones and 90% of them are android based

Comment: Well 40 dollars is really cheap, you'll find a few models but they won't be of a great build quality. Look for micromax, or karbonn. It's gonign to be tough to get a sub $40 phone. Maybe secondhand ?

Comment: @RudraMatroja Did you read the requirements? What I want is a mini tablet, or a phone without reception/2G/3G/4G. I've already provided a link to one that costs $20.

Comment: well this one: http://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/asin/B00REYV0VS/2/
but honestly you're better off with the lg. unless you find a something like this worthy: http://www.amazon.com/HTC-Desire-510-Sprint-Prepaid/dp/B00ODLYMHY/
It's prepaid and it's $10 more but it's HTC.

Comment: @RubyJunk It depends on what you want. If you want simplicity, go with IOS. If you want more control, S6 edge wins. I would get a 6S (not plus) and jailbreak it. I have no prior experience using any of them, just their older syblings. I'm still deciding whether to go with a Nokia or a IPhone. (Yes, I saw your budget.)